# find and write multiple variables from one file to another

Tags: python-2.7

I am fairly new to python and I need help with revising my script. I am really stuck. Any input would be appreciated. TIA!

Text in the original_file looks like this:

```
<Time>
1159
</Time>
<Date>
03042016
</Date>
<Time>
1300
</Time>
<Date>
03052016
</Date>
...
```

My script:

```
with open("original_file.txt", "r") as input_file, \
open("result_file.txt", "w") as output_file:
    input_file.seek(0)
    copy = False
    for line in input_file:
        if line.strip() == "<Time>" or line.strip() == "<Date>":
            copy = True
        elif line.strip() == "</Time>" or line.strip() == "</Date>" :
            copy = False
        elif copy:
            output_file.write(line)
```

My script works but the output looks like this:

```
1159
03042016
1300
03052016
```

My desired output:

```
1159, 03042016
1300, 03052016
```

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining your code, it should look something like this

```
with open("original_file.txt", "r") as input_file, \
open("result_file.txt", "w") as output_file:
    input_file.seek(0)
    values = []
    for line in input_file:
        if line.strip() == "<Time>" or line.strip() == "<Date>":
            pass
        elif line.strip() == "</Time>":
            pass
        elif line.strip() == "</Date>":
            line = ",".join(values)
            output_file.write(line)
            values
        else:
            line.append(line.strip())
```

However, you could use some libraries such as [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), which is a XML parser. Your work is greatly reduced

Using this library, your code would end up being something like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("original_file.txt.html"))
with open("result_file.txt", "w") as output_file:
    results = zip(soup.find_all('Time'), soup.find_all('Date'))
    for time, date in results:
        output_file.write(",".join([time,date]))
```

Comment: Hi Rafael, thank you so much for the input.
I tried the code but it keeps warning me syntax error on line 8. (Last line with any text is line 7.)

Comment: @spiderlily There is one parenthesis missing lol. Correct the last parenthesis (Ive just edited it)